# No write permissions after shared directory mount from fstab

Tags: centos, mount, fstab, shared-folders

**Backstory:**
I have a CentOS image on VirtualBox running on my local machine. (I created a group `hadoop` and user `hduser` to run Hadoop services on it.) I created a folder on my MacOS called `shared`. I did the same in the the VirtualBox image (under user `hduser`).

The directories are successfully mounted in the sense that I can see all files in `shared` from both machines. I can create and paste new files into `shared` on my local machine, but I cannot do the same in the virtual machine.

**Issue:**
There seems to be a write permission error, as I can see all files, but cannot write. Below is me testing to write a file in `shared` on the virtual machine.

```
[Error writing shared/test.txt: Permission Denied]
```

[image: Error writing shared/test.txt: Permission Denied]

Here's the **`permissions`**:
Attempting to write to `shared`.

[image: ls-l]

Here's my **`/etc/fstab`**:
[image]

I have read up on the issue and tried several things from:

> - [Cannot mount vboxsf shared folder via /etc/fstab despite having a modules file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349621/cannot-mount-vboxsf-shared-folder-via-etc-fstab-despite-having-a-modules-file)
> - https://askubuntu.com/questions/365346/virtualbox-shared-folder-mount-from-fstab-fails-works-once-bootup-is-complete

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.   BTW, since this has nothing to do with `nano`, you don't need a screenshot of nano either - `touch shared/test.txt` would have shown the problem, and `grep shared /etc/fstab` would have shown the relevant fstab entry.

Comment: @cas Okay, I wasn't aware. I did attempt to add the text from the images in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue. I initially followed the instructions from this [github post](https://gist.github.com/kentwait/ea49b270f4f7480541409c5ded093ec9) where it is suggested to use these settings:

```
shared    /home/hduser/shared    vboxsf   defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022    0    0
```

However, that didn't work in my case. Instead it is either:

```
shared    /home/hduser/shared    vboxsf   uid=1001 defaults    0    0
```

or

```
shared    /home/hduser/shared    vboxsf   uid=1000 defaults    0    0
```